# Mass editing grouped list of codes to concatenate common code with each individual one

Tags: python, text, replace

I wanted to try something practical and specific in Python and I realized the time I waste plugging in codes when I play Pokemon. There's a text file of codes where a code looks something like this:

*At the very top*(82003884)

0001 = Master Ball
...

The 82003884 code is the base code and the XXXX code (masterball = 0001) is added to the end to get you that specific item.

I want to modify all the codes in the text file so the first and second codes are joined together. The problem is, I don't yet know how to approach it. My first reaction is to search and replace all 4-character "words" with a new word that starts with the master code. But I don't really understand how Python would interpret a line like "0001 = Master Ball" and how to concatenate the longer master code with the 4-character (XXXX) code.

Furthermore, I don't know if a find-replace based on the criteria of 4-characters is selective enough to limit the process only to the codes themselves (and not affect the odd 4-character description word like "nest" etc).

Here's what it looks like:

```
0001 = Master Ball
0002 = Ultra Ball
0003 = Great Ball
0004 = Poke Ball
0005 = Safari Ball
0006 = Net Ball
```

...

Comment: Is the code for the Master Ball 82003885 (adding 1 to the base) or 820038840001 (concatenating)?

Comment: It isn't about working for it, per se, although I can see why you'd think so. It's about commonality between whatever personal tutoring you may need to get these ideas, and whatever personal tutoring any other random person on the Internet might need later to get to a similar place. Specifically, that there is likely to be precious little of that. Which is a problem, because SE is all about common questions, even if "common" means "five people" in some cases. That said, I have an idea for how to convert this. Let's see.

Comment: its concatenating (i believe thats the correct term). Theres no math involved thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it is that there is only one base code. In that case, you can read the first line of the file, and place the contents of this line in front of every other line.

If there are multiple base codes however (which seems more likely), you have to decide how you as a human would decide if something is a base code or not. Is there a whiteline? Is the base code always a string containing 8 digits? Once you know that, you translate that into a rule that Python or any other language understands.

EDIT

Since there is only one basecode, the following script would do already.

**pokemon.txt**

```
12345678
0001 = Master Ball
0002 = Ultra Ball
0003 = Great Ball
0004 = Poke Ball
0005 = Safari Ball
0006 = Net Ball
```

**prepend.py**

```
def prepend_header(file_in, file_out):
    with (open(file_in, 'r')) as f:
        base_code = f.readline()[:-1]  # -1 to strip newline character
        new_string = ''
        for line in f:
            new_string += base_code + line
        print (new_string)

    with (open(file_out, 'w')) as f:
        f.write(new_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prepend_header('pokemon.txt', 'pokemon_new.txt')
```

**pokemon_new.txt**

```
123456780001 = Master Ball
123456780002 = Ultra Ball
123456780003 = Great Ball
123456780004 = Poke Ball
123456780005 = Safari Ball
123456780006 = Net Ball
```

Comment: no whiteline, that was my rudimentary way of depicting it. I edited to add a better example at the bottom of my post if that helps. that sounds perfect however, in regards to "read the first line of the file...", how would I go about that systematically?

Comment: You still only give a portion of the input text file. Give a more elaborate section, including the base codes.

Comment: There's only the one base code (82003884). I only posted the recent lines a few at a time because they are literally all like that and I'm not totally up to speed with formatting here (its not actual "code" but wants to be formatted as such).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is regexen, or regexes: regular expressions. They're wildcards on speed. Here, you want one to match the master code, which would be `^\d{8}$` or perhaps `^\(\d{8}\)$` depending on whether those parentheses are there in the file. Then you save that in a variable and prepend it to every following line before saving all the lines to the file once more.

Example in Python 3.4, assuming the file is named "pokemon_codes.txt" and is in the current directory and so forth:

```
import re   # for regular expressions
import os   # for renaming/deleting files

# open the file line by line, updating into temp file then overwriting
with open('pokemon_codes.txt', mode='r') as f_codes:
with open('pokemon_codes.out', mode='w') as f_out:
    for line in f_codes:
      if re.match('^\d{8}$', line):
        master = line.rstrip()          # now we know what the current master code is
      else:
        f_out.write(master + line)      # update with the master code/current code combination followed by the description, if any
os.remove('pokemon_codes.txt')
os.rename('pokemon_codes.out', 'pokemon_codes.txt')
```